Invalid version (expected 2, but 31) or the data in not in 'javabin' format for Solr8.11.3
Upgrading my Solrj to 8.11.3. Using a java application that uses solr-solrj-8.11.3 to communicate to Solr. Getting the below error.
Invalid version (expected 2, but 31) or the data in not in 'javabin' format

I understand from Similar Solr Question on StackOverflow that Solr is unable to process/parse information coming from the java app.
But not sure how to address the issue ...
Tried with Solr 8.11.2 and solrj8.11.3 and zookeeper3.8.4 ( dependencies for my java app) - this combination works fine.

Check the Solr log - it will generally be caused by an error page being returned instead of the expected serialized format from java.

@MatsLindh I did check the Solr log , didn't get anything useful. But will take your advise and double check. thanks

Also verify that there isn't a reverse proxy in front of the nodes that are getting the request instead of your solr nodes.

i re-checked my logs , there seems to be another issue , I observed that the core is getting created in the solr, but the indexing of the project files / content is not happening - the error is as below
Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got application/json.
I have some configsets that i manually place in the solr installation folder - should i do some changes in them?? The configsets folder contains importantly solrconfig.xml
need some advise on this.

@MatsLindh Please let me know if you have any advise, I'm stuck with this
